# How to count numbers of names from a file using String and File classes in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to learn Objects and Classes. Here is my problem: Each line of the file holds the outcome of a single game: the names of 2 teams together with the scores. I created a file using Notepad which looks like this:

```
Panthers  5  Tigers    5

Sky       2  Panthers  5

Tigers    1  Sky       0

Sky       2  Panthers  1

Tigers    1  Sky       4
```

I tried to read to the file and count number of teams in the file. For example, in this file, there are 3 different teams. "Panthers, Tigers, Sky". But without program the computer doesn't know how many of the teams.

I created a string array in the Soccer class

```
private n;
private String[] team;
```

I use File and Scanner in Soccer(String filename) constructor of the Soccer class to read the file

```
File inputFile = new File(filename);
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(inputFile);
n = 1;

team = new String[n]; // Create a String array of n

team[n-1] = inFile.next();

while(inFile.hasNext()){

    String num = inFile.nextInt(); //For the scores next to team's name 

    String name = inFile.next(); // Read another name and store it to String name

    while(checkDuplicate(name)) // Check if name and team[i=0 to n] are the same return true
   {
      num = inFile.nextInt();
      name = inFile.next();
   }

     n = n + 1; // Increase string array size to 1
     team = new String[n];
     team[n - 1] = name;

}

    System.out.print("Number of teams: " + n);

    System.out.print("Name of the teams: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       System.out.print(team[i] + " ");
```

Down here is my checkDuplicate() helper method

```
private boolean checkDuplicate(String name) 
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(name.equals(team[i]))
          count = count + 1;
    }

    if(count > 1)
       return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Russian Osmanov

Comment: And what exactly is your question? Please be more specific

Comment: I want to use Java to read a file, for example, "scores.txt", and I want to write a program, which can look into the file and see a name of a soccer's team. It stores the name in a String array, ex: String[ ] team, and increase the count to 1. If it sees a name the same as the one in the team[n] String array, it will not store the name to the String array or increase count (count stays the same). In the end, the count is the number of teams.

Comment: My question is to count number of team in the .txt file using Java.

Answer (score 0):

This needs improvement, but you can use it:

```
Map<String, Long> map = Files.lines(Paths.get("score.txt"))
            .flatMap(line -> Stream.of(line.split("\\d+")))
            .map(team -> team.trim())
            .filter(team -> !team.isEmpty())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c, Collectors.counting()));
map.entrySet().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue()));
```

It will provide you a team name and its repetition number.

```
Sky 4
Panthers 3
Tigers 3
```